# Forwarding traffic with one ip proxmox

Tags: iptables, nat, bridge, proxmox, hetzner

I have a hetzner dedicated server, and i've installed proxmox. I have only one ip and i need to forward traffic and ports to VMs. I've followed proxmox network tutorial with no success: can't access from the internet to vm and can't surf the net with the vm. Here my network configuration and kernel log

```
### Hetzner Online GmbH installimage                    

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*                      

auto lo                                                  
iface lo inet loopback                                  
iface lo inet6 loopback                                  

auto enp2s0                                              
iface enp2s0 inet static                                
  address 1.2.3.4                              
  netmask 255.255.255.224                                
  gateway 2.3.4.5                              
  up route add -net 1.2.3.4 netmask 255.255.255.224

iface enp2s0 inet6 static                                
  address indirizzo ipv6                          
  netmask 64                                            
  gateway fe80::1                                        


auto vmbr2                                              
iface vmbr2 inet static                                  
    address 10.10.10.254                                
    netmask 255.255.255.0                                
    bridge_ports none                                    
    bridge_stp off                                      
    bridge_fd 0                                          

    post-up echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
       post-up   iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s '10.10.10.0/24' -o enp2s0 -j MASQUERADE        
    post-down iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -s '10.10.10.0/24' -o enp2s0 -j MASQUERADE
```

dmesg:

```
[359074.849541] device tap100i0 entered promiscuous mode                                      

[359074.855293] vmbr2: port 1(tap100i0) entered blocking state                                

[359074.855347] vmbr2: port 1(tap100i0) entered disabled state                                

[359074.855486] vmbr2: port 1(tap100i0) entered blocking state                                

[359074.855539] vmbr2: port 1(tap100i0) entered forwarding state                              

[359417.355699] vmbr2: port 1(tap100i0) entered disabled state                                

[359417.358959] vmbr2: port 1(tap100i0) entered disabled state
```

Thanks

Comment: Try `bridge_ports enp2s0` in `iface vmbr2` confiig. That's the only difference with mine, except IP MASQUERADE, not too sure why you need it here. But, hey whatever floats your boat.